# UBUNTU to WIN 7 without data loss

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, bootmgr

I accidently compressed my c drive in Windows 7 and ended up with "bootmgr is compressed" error. I had to install Ubuntu to get some files. After that I went online and found some solutions for fixing the 'bootmgr' error. Can I go back to Windows 7 without losing any data? I heard that Ubuntu formats the hdd to a format that Windows does not recognise. What should I do? I am sure I didn't do a full installation of Ubuntu. And also how can I remove Ubuntu completely?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has *loads* of supported filesystem types, including the everything-friendly FAT to Linux-only ext4. Search for *disks* in the dash and see if you can change the Windows partition back to FAT if it's been changed.